# Использование вк бота несколькими людьми

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Столкнулся с проблемой:

У бота в вк есть подменю, если несколько человек напишут этому боту, то все они все будут находится в этом подменю. Пытался решить эту проблему с помощью многопоточности - ничего не получилось.

```
import requests, json
token = 'tokenplaceholdertokenplaceholdertokenplaceholder'
torproxy = {'http': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050', 'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}


def GetMessage():
    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getConversations?count=1&access_token={}&v=5.80'.format(token), proxies=torproxy)
    data = response.json()
    last_message = data['response']['items'][0]['last_message']
    text = last_message['text']
    user_id = last_message['from_id']
    attachments = last_message['attachments']
    if attachments != []:
        attachments = attachments[0]['type']
    out = last_message['out']
    peer_id = last_message['peer_id']
    return {'text':text,
            'user_id': user_id,
            'attachments': attachments,
            'out': out,
            'peer_id': peer_id}



def Keyboard(label1='1',label2='2',label3='3',label4='4',):
    false = False 
    true = True
    keys = json.dumps({"one_time":true,"buttons":[[{"action":{"type":"text","label":label1},"color":"default"},{"action":{"type":"text","label":label2},"color":"default"}],[{"action":{"type":"text","label":label3},"color":"default"},{"action":{"type":"text","label":label4},"color":"default"}]]})
    return keys
def SendMessageWithKeyboard(user_id, text, keyboard=Keyboard()):
    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id={}&message={}&keyboard={}&access_token={}&v=5.80'.format(user_id, text, keyboard, token), proxies=torproxy)




def MessageSend(user_id, text):
    response = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id={}&message={}&access_token={}&v=5.80'.format(user_id, text,token), proxies=torproxy)

def main():
    while True:
        data = GetMessage()
        if data != None: 
            text = data['text']
            attachments = data['attachments']
            user_id = data['user_id']
            if text == 'Привет':
                SendMessageWithKeyboard(user_id, '3 * 3 = ', Keyboard('6', '9', '12', '14'))
                while True:
                    data = GetMessage()
                    if data != None: 
                        text = data['text']
                        attachments = data['attachments']
                        user_id = data['user_id']


                        if text == '6' or text == '12' or text == '14':
                            SendMessageWithKeyboard(user_id, 'Это не верный ответ :(', Keyboard('6', '9', '12', '14'))
                        elif text == '9':
                            MessageSend(user_id, 'Это верный ответ :)')
                            break
                        else:
                            SendMessageWithKeyboard(user_id, 'Ответь!', Keyboard('6', '9', '12', '14'))

            elif attachments == 'photo':
                MessageSend(user_id, 'Я не вижу картинок (')
            else:
                MessageSend(user_id, 'Я не понимаю тебя')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

После того, как боту написал человек, начинается 2 бесконечный цикл. Если пишет кто-то другой, программа уже находится в цикле, где у бота активирована клавиатура. Убери второй while True и все будет о`кей